# Using SimpleCursorTreeAdapter for ExpandableList gives error "Failed to read row 0, column -1". Can't find the bug

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, exception, cursor

I want to get data from a SQLite db and populate my ExpandableListView via a SimpleCursorTreeAdapter, but it fails somewehere. I really can't find what's wrong, don't even know where the exception is happening...

MyExpandableListAdapter:

```
private class MyExpandableListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter
    {       

        public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor,
                int groupLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo,
                int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {
            super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childFrom,
                    childTo);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
            Log.d("Calling getChildrenCursor()","OK");
            Cursor childrenCursor = dbAdapter.getTrackedValuesByDate(groupCursor.getString(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.KEY_VALUE_DATE)));
            Log.d("getChildrenCursor()", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(childrenCursor));
            startManagingCursor(childrenCursor);

            return childrenCursor;
        }       
    }
```

Here's the relevant part in my activity to set the ListAdapter:

```
private void fillData()
    {
        Cursor dateCursor = dbAdapter.getAllDates();
        startManagingCursor(dateCursor);
        Log.d("fillData()", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(dateCursor));
        MyExpandableListAdapter myAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(this, 
        dateCursor, 
        R.layout.expandablelist_header_date, 
        new String[] {DbAdapter.KEY_VALUE_DATE},    
        new int[]{R.id.expandablelist_header_date},             
        R.layout.listview_tracked_values, 
        new String[] {DbAdapter.KEY_INDICATOR_NAME, DbAdapter.KEY_INDICATOR_UNIT, DbAdapter.KEY_VALUE_VALUE},
        new int[]{R.id.list_trackedvalue_indicatorname, R.id.list_trackedvalue_unit, R.id.list_trackedvalue_value });

        Log.d("fillData()", "Creation successful");     
        this.expandableList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        Log.d("fillData()", "Adapter set");
    }
```

Here are the two used functions of my dbAdapter:

```
public Cursor getTrackedValuesByDate(String dateString)
    {
        Cursor cursor = this.db.rawQuery("select * from "+DB_INDICATORS_TABLE+" i,"+ DB_VALUES_TABLE+" v where i."
        + KEY_INDICATOR_ROWID+"=v."+KEY_VALUE_INDICATOR_ID+" and v."+KEY_VALUE_DATE+"='"+dateString+"'", null);

        if(cursor!=null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Log.d("getTrackedValuesByDate()", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
        return cursor;
    }

    public Cursor getAllDates()
    {
        Cursor c = this.db.rawQuery("Select distinct "+KEY_VALUE_DATE+" from "+DB_VALUES_TABLE, null);
        if(c!=null)
            c.moveToFirst();

        Log.d("getAllDates()", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(c));
        return c;
    }
```

And finally the output of LogCat:

```
09-07 12:05:06.912: D/fillData()(1317): >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41219990
09-07 12:05:06.912: D/fillData()(1317): 0 {
09-07 12:05:06.912: D/fillData()(1317):    trackDate=07.09.2012
09-07 12:05:06.912: D/fillData()(1317): }
09-07 12:05:06.912: D/fillData()(1317): 1 {
09-07 12:05:06.912: D/fillData()(1317):    trackDate=08.08.2012
09-07 12:05:06.912: D/fillData()(1317): }
09-07 12:05:06.912: D/fillData()(1317): <<<<<
09-07 12:05:06.952: D/fillData()(1317): Creation successful
09-07 12:05:06.952: D/fillData()(1317): Adapter set
09-07 12:05:07.012: E/CursorWindow(1317): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 1 columns.
09-07 12:05:07.012: D/AndroidRuntime(1317): Shutting down VM
09-07 12:05:07.048: W/dalvikvm(1317): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:507)
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:75)
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter$MyCursorHelper.getId(CursorTreeAdapter.java:436)
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter.getGroupId(CursorTreeAdapter.java:191)
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getItemId(ExpandableListConnector.java:422)
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2288)
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:602)
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:415)
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-07 12:05:07.145: E/AndroidRuntime(1317):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
```

As you can see, my last debug.log is that the Adapter is set to the ListView, but then
it's finnito...
I don't even get a log message that the overriden function getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) is ever called, so the error happens I don't know where...

Help, I'm going mad on this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [CursorTreeAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorTreeAdapter.html), which is an indirect parent of SimpleCursorTreeAdapter you can see that:

> The Cursors must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.

Which you were missing from your queries.

Answer (score 1):

couple of points

You may have an empty Cursor returned (i.e. does not return null) so instead of checking c != null try checking the cursor column count or a check on c.moveToNext check instead

Also wrap all your rawQuery and Cursor methods with a try{}catch(SQLiteException)

Logging this exception may reveal more

Comment: I did as you suggested but still the same, so the queries return something and there is no exception triggered by them :-(

Comment: The fact that column == -1 means that column does not exist you need you could check the values when setting up your adapter

Comment: But the problem is that the columns really exist (I use constants for each of them), which makes it so strange... and it's not possible to trace back the error :-/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was not able to get it to work with the SimpleTreeAdapter... simply can't find the error. What I did now was to skip the TreeAdapter and fill the contents of the cursors into Collections, then populate the list via a BaseExpandableListAdapter.

It's more complicated and not as elegant as the SimpleTreeAdapter, but at least it works now ;-)